# Accepting user input using a form and perform calculations & display it using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I am trying to use an html form to accept my user input then do the calculations on javascript, it just displays the dialogue box without the calculations, what could be the problem? I don't know how to go about it, this is what I tried so far.

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Air() {
    input = document.getElementById('Enter').value;
    TotalPurchasingAmountOrange = 0.87 * input;
    discountOrange = 0.13 * input;
    TotalPurchasingAmountMascom = 0.85 * input;
    discountMascom = 0.15 * input;
    TotalPurchasingAmountBMobile = 0.83 * input;
    discountMascom = 0.17 * input;
    alert("Orange airtime:\nAmount: " + TotalPurchasingAmountOrange + "\nDiscount: " + discountOrange);
    alert("Mascom airtime:\nAmount: " + TotalPurchasingAmountMascom + "\nDiscount: " + discountMascom + "\nBMobile airtime:\nAmount: " + TotalPurchasingAmountBMobile + "\nDiscount: " + discountBMobile);
}
</script>
```

Form

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label>Units
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: units" />
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="buttonArea">
    <input id="Enter" type="button" value="Enter" onclick="Air()" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
input = document.getElementById('Enter').value;
...
<input id="Enter" type="button" value="Enter" onclick="Air()"/>
```

`Enter` has a value of "Enter", so when you try to multiply that by `0.87`, I suspect that you're either getting a console error or javascript is trying to be smart and figure out the value and is getting it completely wrong.

This is what you want:

```
<input type="text" id="Enter">
<input type="button" value="Enter" onclick="Air()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input = document.getElementById('Enter').value;
```

First of all, please, use "var" before initializing variables, unless "input" is global variable.
Second, according to your code, **input** value will be "Enter". And right after that you try to multiply it by some numbers. Even JS cannot provide this kind of calculations.

You need to use

```
<input type="text" id="Enter" />
```

to allow users to write their own values.

or you can use dialog window via prompt function.
It will look like:

```
function Air (){
    while (isNaN(amount)) {
        var input = prompt("Please, enter needed amount. Notice, that it should be number");
        var amount = parseFloat(input);
    }

    var TotalPurchasingAmountOrange = 0.87 * amount;
    var discountOrange = 0.13 * amount;

    var TotalPurchasingAmountMascom = 0.85 * amount;
    var discountMascom = 0.15 * amount;

    var TotalPurchasingAmountBMobile = 0.83 * amount;
    var discountMascom = 0.17 * amount;

    alert("Orange airtime:\nAmount: " +TotalPurchasingAmountOrange+ "\nDiscount: " +discountOrange );

    alert("Mascom airtime:\nAmount: " +TotalPurchasingAmountMascom+ "\nDiscount: " +discountMascom+ "\nBMobile airtime:\nAmount: " +TotalPurchasingAmountBMobile+ "\nDiscount: " +discountBMobile  );
}
```

Comment: Its running perfect.Now i am trying to display the output using a jquery dialog, do I write the dialogue method within the javascript method?

Answer (score 0):

You get the value of `Enter` in your Javascript. If you perform an `alert(input)` after you've assigned the variable, you'll notice its value is `Enter`, the text on the button. Not what you're trying to do, I guess!

Add to your HTML, for instance :

```
<input id="number" type="textbox">
```

And change your first Javasvript line :

```
input = document.getElementById('number').value;
```

Input a value into the textbox and you should notice actual numbers showing up in your last two `alert` calls!